# High CPU load for Firefox 29 and HUD with Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, firefox, cpu-load, hud

Using Firefox 29.0 on the recently upgraded Ubuntu 13.10 results in high CPU load. By running `top` on the commandline I can see that the high CPU load goes to the following processes:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND           
 3540 dupo      20   0  236m 175m 2768 R  28.5  5.8 111:21.84 hud-service       
32469 dupo      20   0 1051m 427m  50m S  13.3 14.1   9:38.83 firefox           
 3809 dupo      20   0  424m  65m  16m R   3.6  2.2  33:27.02 compiz            
 3503 dupo      20   0  6904 3156  904 S   1.7  0.1   7:00.64 dbus-daemon       
 3549 dupo      20   0  213m  86m 9856 S   1.7  2.8  23:36.36 unity-panel-ser   
 3863 dupo      20   0 53516 5168 4024 S   1.7  0.2  11:34.61 indicator-multi   
 1725 root      20   0  439m  96m  64m S   1.3  3.2  57:24.35 Xorg
```

This occupies constantly **at least** one quarter of the CPU capacity of the PC (2 CPUs). It gets worse while browsing, particularly when it comes to pages with a lot of background JSON, such as Fbook. After some time the computer gets too slow and occasionally irresponsive, preventing me from typing in a website text field or so. In that case, the only solution is restarting Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/987060

Adding Firefox to the ignore list in privacy settings doesn't help.

Comment: In Ubuntu 12.04-12.10 I had solved this problem by moving the bookmarks from the toolbar and the menu, to "Unsorted Bookmarks". Back then, bookmarks which were not in the menu, did not get tracked by hud and therefore did not create an issue any more. 

After having upgraded to 13.10, the issue is back. I haven't confirmed that unsorted bookmarks get tracked again, but I start assuming that this is the case. 

Funny thing is that things do not get improved by killing hud-service